# How to draw a filled circle without using multiplication?

Tags: math, graphics

Say that you are in a constrained computing environment where the multiplication operation is expensive or unavailable. You have access to a stream of pixels for an image of known dimensions. How would you draw a circle overlay onto the image?

Comment: Note, it is perfectly acceptable to ask and answer your own question for the purposes of sharing something you think others may find useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Python script that demonstrates how you would draw a circle without using multiplication. It uses the formula x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> > r<sup>2</sup> to check whether the current pixel position (x, y) is outside the circle.

One can maintain a running computation of the squared values by using **addition**, since [the rate of change of the difference between the squares of adjacent pixel indices is 2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+%28%28x+%2B+1%29%5E2+-x%5E2%29). As you iterate through pixels, you'll keep adding a number (call that number `z`) to your running "squares" computations, and for each pixel, you will also add 2 to `z`.

The `__init__` function below does contain some multiplication operations. However, if the image dimensions are constant, the **compiler** will perform the multiplication and only load the **result** onto the device. If the image dimensions are not constant, a "slow" multiplication need only be performed once upon startup, as opposed to once per pixel.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

class CircularMaskGenerator:
    '''Generates a circular "mask" for an image.
    Maintains a running computation of squared values to eliminate the need for multiplication'''

    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.image_width = w
        self.image_height = h

        # Precompute some important values.
        # The embedded device doesn't actaully have to do this math; the
        # compiler does it before loading the code onto the device.

        self.half_image_width = self.image_width >> 1
        self.half_image_height = self.image_height >> 1
        self.radius = self.half_image_height

        self.squared_half_image_width = self.half_image_width*self.half_image_width
        self.squared_half_image_height = self.half_image_height*self.half_image_height
        self.squared_radius = self.radius*self.radius

        # The "deltas" are the difference between the squared values of adjacent pixel indices.
        self.initial_x_squared_delta = 1 - self.image_width
        self.initial_y_squared_delta = 1 - self.image_height

        self.resetFrame()

    def resetFrame(self):

        # Start with a white binary image
        import Image
        self.image = Image.new("1", (self.image_width, self.image_height), 1)
        self.pixels = self.image.load()

        # Reset indices
        self.resetColumnIndex()
        self.resetRowIndex()

    def processPixel(self):

        # Write a black pixel if we're outside the circle
        if self.current_x_squared + self.current_y_squared > self.squared_radius:
            self.pixels[(self.current_column_index, self.current_row_index)] = 0

        self.updateIndices()

    def updateIndices(self):
        '''Update the indices and squares values'''

        self.incrementColumnIndex()

        # Wrap to the next row if necessary
        if self.current_column_index == self.image_width:
            self.incrementRowIndex()

            # Wrap to the next frame if necessary
            if self.current_row_index == self.image_height:
                self.writeImage()
                self.resetFrame()

    def incrementColumnIndex(self):
        self.current_column_index += 1
        self.current_x_squared += self.current_x_squared_delta
        self.current_x_squared_delta += 2

    def resetColumnIndex(self):
        self.current_column_index = 0
        self.current_x_squared = self.squared_half_image_width
        self.current_x_squared_delta = self.initial_x_squared_delta

    def incrementRowIndex(self):
        '''The row increment has to send the column index back to the left.'''

        self.resetColumnIndex()

        self.current_row_index += 1
        self.current_y_squared += self.current_y_squared_delta
        self.current_y_squared_delta += 2

    def resetRowIndex(self):
        self.current_row_index = 0
        self.current_y_squared = self.squared_half_image_height
        self.current_y_squared_delta = self.initial_y_squared_delta

    def writeImage(self):
        '''Save the image in PNG format in the current directory'''
        self.image.save("output.png", "PNG")

# =============================================================================
def simulate_system():

    image_width = 800
    image_height = 600

    # initialize the system
    circle_processor = CircularMaskGenerator(image_width, image_height)

    # supply a pixel stream to drive the system
    for i in xrange(image_width*image_height):
        circle_processor.processPixel()

# =============================================================================
if __name__ == "__main__":
    simulate_system()
```

This code creates a centered circle like so:

[image]

Comment: This should be posted along with the question, not as an answer. cheers :)

Comment: How are the multiplications in `__init__` going to be handled if multiplication is not available in a constrained architecture, as per your question ?

Comment: If the image dimensions are constant, the compiler will perform the multiplication and only load the result onto the device.

Comment: Or, if the image dimensions are not constant, the "slow" multiplication (perhaps implemented as an addition loop) need only be performed once upon startup, as opposed to once per pixel.

Comment: OK - you should probably add this to your answer for clarification

Comment: I've seen versions of this (30+ years ago) that plot 8 pixels for each iteration, allowing for 4 planes of reflective symmetry

Answer (score 2):

The well-known [midpoint circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) draws a circle using only addition and subtraction.